# What is the meaning of size(embedding_model)?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to be sure I understand correctly:

Using the length of embedding model means number of different tokens it contains?

i.e:

```
from gensim import downloader
embedding_model = downloader.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-50')
print(len(embedding_model))
```

output:

```
400000
```

means: `glove-wiki-gigaword-50` has 400000 different tokens (words) and each token (word) has the size of 50 bytes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `len(model)` in this case gives you the count of words inside it.

`model.vector_size` will give you the number of dimensions (not bytes) per vector. (The actual size of the vector in bytes will be 4 times the count of dimensions, as each `float32`-sized value takes 4 bytes.)

I generally recommend against ever using the Gensim `api.downloader` functionality: if you instead find & manually download from the original source of the files, you'll better understand their contents, formats, & limitations – and where the file has landed in your local filesystem. And, by then using a specific class/method to load the file, you'll better understand what kinds of classes/objects you're using, rather than whatever mystery-object `downloader.load()` might have given you.